# How does a shared_ptr handle copy to a pure virtual base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr

`Class B` expects to receive an instance of `shared_ptr<IError>`.
`Class A` implements `IError` and is passed by value to the constructor of `B`.

I would like to understand how this scenario is handled. How does the `shared_ptr` as a template class handle the conversion to `IError`?

In a simple case where `B` receives `shared_ptr<A>` I assume the copy constructor is called and the reference counter is increased. However since `IError` is pure virtual a normal copy constructor invocation seems not to be case here?

```
// Example program

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class IError 
{    
    public:
        virtual ~IError(){};
        virtual void OnError() = 0;
};

 

class A : public IError 
{
    public:
       A(){};
       void OnError(){std::cout << "Error Occured" << std::endl;} 
};

class B
{
  public:
     B(std::shared_ptr<IError> errorReporter): mErrorReporter(errorReporter){}
     void Action(){mErrorReporter->OnError();}

  private:   
     std::shared_ptr<IError> mErrorReporter;
};

int main()
{
    auto objA = std::make_shared<A>();
    auto objB = std::make_shared<B>(objA);
    objB->Action();
}
```

Comment: Take a step back and ask yourself why you think the copy constructor of the `shared_ptr` would invoke the copy constructor of the thing it points to.

Comment: "the copy constructor is called and the reference counter is increased" doesn't really make sense, if it's copy then it should not use same reference count

Comment: @appleapple -- no, that's exactly what the copy constructor for `std::shared_ptr` does: it increases the reference count. The confusion is about copying the object that the shared pointer points at; shared pointers don't do that.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish I did some reading and I think I understand now, that the underlying object is not copied. Instead only a copy of the pointer to the control block of the shared_ptr<A> is created. I have some more questions, but I guess it would be to much to discuss in this question.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was think OP means copy constructor of underlying object, but yes, your interpretation make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging time! Let's find out what happens by using the tools we have available as developers.

The memory of the shared_ptr `objA` looks like this (type `&objA` in the memory window; it will be replaced by its address):

[image: objA]

It has a pointer to the object (`000002172badd8e0`) and a pointer to the control block.

The control block looks like this (copy and paste the second value into a new memory window):

[image: objA control block]

It has a pointer to the allocator (first 2 columns), the reference count (1) and the weak reference count (0 + offset 1).

After `objB` has been created, the control block of `objA` has changed to a reference count of 2:

[image: objA control block after copy]

And the shared_ptr `objB` looks like this:

[image: objB]

It points to the a shared pointer and to the control block.

[image: Shared pointer of objB]

The shared pointer in objB points to the same object as before (`000002172badd8e0`), so no copy of the actual object has been made.

The control block of `objB` indicates that `objB` only has a reference count of 1:

[image: objB control block]

> a normal copy constructor invocation seems not to be case here?

Correct. No copy of the object is made, as we can confirm with a debugger. But a copy of the shared_ptr has been made.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.

---

Copy a `shared_ptr` doesn't copy it's point-to object, just like normal **pointer**

```
std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
std::shared_ptr<IError> i = a;
```

```
A* a = new A;
IError* i = a; // no copy A
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did some reading and understand now that shared_ptr<IError> only has a copy of the pointer to the control block. Still having some questions, but I think it is out of scope for this question. I will wait a bit longer before I accept your answer.

Comment: @Galik fixed, thanks. was deciding to use `A` or `A*`

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that the base class `IError` is abstract, hence it cannot be instantiated, never mind copied.

The code below has been modified from the original to show how each newly created `shared_ptr` just increments the reference count of the original `shared_ptr`. So, a shallow copy.

In your code, as well as in the code below, the underlying object to these `shared_ptr`s is concrete class `A`, derived from the abstract `IError`, so it is legal to shallow copy it.

```
// Example program

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class IError 
{    
    public:
        virtual ~IError(){};
        virtual void OnError() = 0;
};

class A : public IError 
{
    public:
       A(){std::cout << "A created.\n";};
       void OnError(){std::cout << "Error Occured" << std::endl;} 
};

class B
{
  public:
     B(std::shared_ptr<IError> errorReporter): mErrorReporter(errorReporter){
         std::cout << "B created from A.\n";
     }
     void Action(){mErrorReporter->OnError();}

  private:   
     std::shared_ptr<IError> mErrorReporter;
};

int main()
{
    auto objA = std::make_shared<A>();
    std::cout << "I. Reference count for objA: " << objA.use_count() << '\n'; 
    auto objB = std::make_shared<B>(objA);
    std::cout << "II. Reference count for objA: " << objA.use_count() << '\n'; 
    // objB->Action();
    auto objBB = std::make_shared<B>(*objB);
    std::cout << "Created objBB from objB\n"; 
    std::cout << "III. Reference count for objA: " << objA.use_count() << '\n';    
    std::cout << "Reference count for objB: " << objB.use_count() << '\n'; 
    std::cout << "Reference count for objBB: " << objBB.use_count() << '\n';
    // auto objB_from_base = std::make_shared<B>(IError()); // ERROR: IError is an abstract class
}
```

with output:

```
A created.
I. Reference count for objA: 1
B created from A.
II. Reference count for objA: 2
Created objBB from objB
III. Reference count for objA: 3
Reference count for objB: 1
Reference count for objBB: 1
```